# UriMatcher doesn't match correctly

Tags: java, android, uri, android-contentprovider

First up: I have sifted through many of the questions on the topic on SO and have still failed to come up with a correct answer.

Here is a, (way simplified), version of my code:

```
private static UriMatcher
        uriMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);

private static final int
        HOMEWORK_TABLE_REQUEST = 1,
        CLASS_TABLE_REQUEST = 2,
        SETTINGS_TABLE_REQUEST = 3,
        HOMEWORK_ITEM_REQUEST = 4,
        CLASS_ITEM_REQUEST = 5,
        SETTINGS_ITEM_REQUEST = 6;

static {
    uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkReminder.homeworkProvider", "homework", HOMEWORK_TABLE_REQUEST);
    uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkreminder.homeworkProvider", "homework/#", HOMEWORK_ITEM_REQUEST);
    uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkReminder.homeworkProvider", "class", CLASS_TABLE_REQUEST);
    uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkreminder.homeworkProvider", "class/#", CLASS_ITEM_REQUEST);
    uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkReminder.homeworkProvider", "settings", SETTINGS_TABLE_REQUEST);
    uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkreminder.homeworkProvider", "settings/#", SETTINGS_ITEM_REQUEST);
}
```

And here is my query method:

```
@Override
public Cursor query(Uri uri, String[] projection, String selection, String[] selectionArgs, String sortOrder) {
    Cursor cursor = null;   
    Log.i("dfg", "Query method called");
    Log.i("dfg", "Uri = " + uri.toString());
    Log.i("dfg", "Match: " + uriMatcher.match(uri));
    switch(uriMatcher.match(uri)) {
        case HOMEWORK_ITEM_REQUEST:
            Log.i("dfg", "HOMEWORK_ITEM_REQUEST");
            cursor = database.readCursorById(Integer.parseInt(uri.getLastPathSegment()));
            break;
        case HOMEWORK_TABLE_REQUEST:
            Log.i("dfg", "HOMEWORK_TABLE_REQUEST");
            cursor = database.readAllHomework();
            break;
        case CLASS_ITEM_REQUEST:
        case CLASS_TABLE_REQUEST:
        case SETTINGS_ITEM_REQUEST:
        case SETTINGS_TABLE_REQUEST:
            cursor = null;
            break;
        default:
            cursor = null;
            break;
    }
    return cursor;
}
```

I have no implementation for my class requests or settings requests so that's why I'm just defaulting to return `null`. What's happening is my `switch` statement is falling all the way through to `default:`, and causing NPE's galore later on in my code. You'll notice there are 5 `Log` statements in my code. The following is printed to LogCat. (Why is it called logcat anyways?)

```
Query method called
Uri = content://org.dvc.homeworkReminder.homeworkProvider/homework/24
Match: -1
```

Now the uri being tested should match the 2nd pattern I added, correct? I also read about how the `Uri.parse()` method messes with `UriMatcher`'s wildcards on another thread so I build the above-printed `Uri` with the following code:

```
Uri returnUri = new Uri.Builder().scheme(ContentResolver.SCHEME_CONTENT).authority("org.dvc.homeworkReminder.homeworkProvider").appendPath("homework").appendPath(String.valueOf(id)).build();
```

The `id` variable there depends on some other stuff that isn't really relevant.

My question is why is `UriMatcher` not working, and how would I go about fixing it?

### Fix:

I had incorrect capitalization on the following lines:

```
uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkreminder.homeworkProvider", "homework/#", HOMEWORK_ITEM_REQUEST);
uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkreminder.homeworkProvider", "class/#", CLASS_ITEM_REQUEST);
uriMatcher.addURI("org.dvc.homeworkreminder.homeworkProvider", "settings/#", SETTINGS_ITEM_REQUEST);
```

Notice the lowercase `r` in `homeworkreminder`. Thanks to Bruce for spotting it!

Comment: The matcher is returning "minus one", not "one"?

Comment: The matcher is returning negative one, which is, according to the JavaDoc, what it does when it can't find a match.

Comment: Ah, I see, that's the problem - you're expecting it to match. My mistake.

Comment: Yes. Did I assemble the pattern correctly in `addUri()`?

Comment: I'm no expert, but I notice you have lower-case 'reminder' when you set up the matcher, but the actual URI has upper-case 'Reminder'. I'm not sure if that is supposed to matter.

Comment: Praise the lordie! Wow, how did I miss that? Thanks so much, it worked. I guess I've been staring at this screen for way too long and needed a fresh pair of eyes. Thanks again. :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53894/discussion-between-bruce-and-andrew-g)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using lower-case 'reminder' when you set up the matcher, but the actual URI has upper-case 'Reminder'.